# variation of a function over countable intervals

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, measure-theory

Let $f$ be a function of bounded variation on $[0,1]$. Let $\{[a_n,b_n]\}_{n=1}^\infty$  such that $(a_n,b_n)$ are pairwise disjoint and $\cup_{n=1}^\infty [a_n,b_n]=[0,1]$. (for example, $[1/2, 1], [0,1/3], [1/3,1/3+1/3^2], \cdots$ ) Can we write

$$
\operatorname{Var}_{[0,1]} f=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \operatorname{Var}_{[a_k,b_k]} f?
$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your example intervals, suppose that $f$ is $0$ on $[0,1/2)$ and $1$ on $[1/2,1]$.

Comment: I'm curious as to why this answer got downvoted.  It gives a function that has variation equal to 1 on [0,1] and whose variation on each interval of the specified partition is 0.  This seems to provide a valid counterexample to the question being asked... so what have I missed that makes this worth a downvote?

Comment: I also believe this is a good counterexample. But it looks somehow fragile, because for $C^1$ functions we know that $\operatorname{Var}_{[a,b]}f = \int_a^b |f'(x)|\, dx$, and the conjecture seems to be true.

Comment: Granted, but the OP hasn't placed any restrictions on their function f so I don't think the answer was worth downvoting.  However, perhaps you could add an answer that addresses the issue of the function-class that f belongs to?

Comment: I suspect it is true for continuous functions but haven't thought it through.