# Sum of total variation over countable partition of interval equals variation over interval?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, bounded-variation, total-variation

Let $I=[a,b]$, and consider some $f\in BV(I)$ (the space of all functions with bounded total variation on $I$). Let 
$$\mathcal Q=\{[a_k,b_k]:k\in\mathbb N,~\operatorname{cl}\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty[a_k,b_k]\right)=I,~(a_k,b_k)\cap(a_j,b_j)=\emptyset~\forall i\neq j \}.$$
In their book, *Laws of Chaos:
Invariant Measures
and Dynamical Systems
in One Dimension*, Gora and Boyarsky claim in a problem that it is possible for 
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty V_{[a_k,b_k]}(f)<V_I(f).$$
I struggle to see how this is true, and believe I have a proof that 
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty V_{[a_k,b_k]}(f)=V_I(f).$$
Now this question is pretty much the same as [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/874509/variation-of-a-function-over-countable-intervals) one, but I do not think the accepted answer there is actually correct, as the example given shows that we can have 
$$V_{[a,c)}(f)+V_{[c,d]}(f)<V_I(f),$$
but the variation of a function over half open intervals is very different from that over closed intervals, so this does not actually address the question. In fact we know that we always have
$$V_{[a,c]}(f)+V_{[c,d]}(f)=V_I(f).$$
My supposed proof for the countable case is a standard approximation argument showing inequalities both ways, but it is quite long to type out, and Boyarski and Gora are much wiser than me so my proof is most probably wrong. Thus before I go through the effort of typing it out I'd appreciate some input from the learned members here, because I might be being silly and missing an easy counterexample.

EDIT: On inspecting the fantastic answer by mathcounterexamples.net I realised that I misinterpreted the given counterexample in the linked post, and it is actually shows perfectly what fails in the countable case. Thus I will be flagging this post as a duplicate, as it adds nothing new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t understand why you aren’t satisfied with the proof of the post you refer to.

Take $a=0$ and $b=1$, $a_1=1/2$, $b_1=1$, $a_k=\sum\limits_{l=2}^k \frac{1}{2^{l-1}}-1/2$ and $b_k = a_k +1/2^k$ for $k\ge 2$. The intervals $[a_k, b_k]$ satisfy the hypothesis.

And 
$$f(x) =\begin{cases}
0 & 0 \le x <1/2\\
1 & 1/2 \le x \le 1
\end{cases}$$

However
$$0 = \sum_{k=1}^\infty V_{[a_k,b_k]}(f)\neq V_{[0,1]}(f)=1.$$

Comment: On looking at my linked post again I realise I misinterpreted the question, as I didn't pick up that the function was supposed to be taken over the example interval given in the answer. So I actually am happy with that counterexample.

Comment: Thanks for your answer though, as it highlighted where my thinking went wrong in the countable case, I was working under the unconscious assumption that the union of sub-intervals actually equalled the given interval.

Comment: I marked my post as duplicate, because now that I'm interpreting the answer in the linked post correctly I realise my question adds nothing new, and your answer, which is a more fleshed out version of the one given there in essence, will still be visible. I hope this causes you no offence. Thanks again for the good answer.